# Paypal Status Pending and Delivery

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm creating a script that includes paypal instant payment. Now i'm recieving money in sandbox. Everything is all right. But i don't know what will i do when the status is pending. I didn't activate my script.

I have to know what will happen when i activate my script. A customer will order. And payment process starts. When customer paid, he/she redirects my website. And the status is pending. I'll write this data to my database.

What about next ? Will we wait until the pending status change ? when will we send goodies to customer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one other reason why the Payment status is pending. If you are sending **doAuthorization** then the funds will always be in a status of pending until you capture the funds.

Directly from the PayPal Documentation:
For example, an unsettled authorization's PaymentStatus is set to **Pending;** however, its PendingReason is set to authorization, which is not related to payment review.

You will need to capture the funds, or set your payment action to Sale. All an authorization does is freeze the money on the card or in the PayPal account, but does not send the money to your PayPal Account. Funds are not sent to your PayPal account until the Authorization is Captured.

From the PayPal Documentation:
To capture an authorization send this API Call: DoCapture

You send the amount you want to capture and the Authorization ID to PayPal and the actual money is moved from the consumer's funding source to the PayPal account.

Just in case you need it, here is the Express Checkout Integration documentation:
[Express Checkout Integration Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/#use-cases)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wait until the transaction is complete to ship the products.

As it's mentioned in the below link

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOtherAPIOps/

*If **PaymentStatus** is set to Pending and the **PendingReason** is set to **PaymentReview**, you should not ship merchandise or, in the case of electronic media, you should not allow download access.*