# PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS was Pending

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using PayPal's Express checkout to do a payment for an customer of ours. To confirm/finalize the payment a call to "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" is made. The PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS in PayPal's response is set to "Pending" instead of "Completed".

Meaning a few things, mostly:

- Customer currency is different then the companies currency.
- The money on the user's account wasn't sufficient.

How should I handle this? Should I setup IPN for this, make cronjob check the payment a few days later or will PayPal return a second time to my succes URL?

Comment: Please provide PAYMENTINFO_n_PENDINGREASON value from response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that you are sending a doAuthorization API Call then the status will be pending until you capture the authorization.

Here is a similar post that gives information on Express Checkout pending transactions. Both answers have detailed reasons why a payment is pending for Express Checkout:

[Stack Question Pending PayPal Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413652/paypal-status-pending-and-delivery/23415129#23415129)

So you either need a payment action of Sale or you need to capture your authorization.

From the PayPal Documentation to ensure that the transaction is completed you need to pass the following API Call:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
```

You can find more information on the PayPal Developer Site:
[PayPal Express Checkout Payment Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/#use-cases)