# Once a payment is complete, it is referred to as a sale?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

In the PayPal rest docs, it states
"Once a payment is complete, it is referred to as a sale. You can then look up the sale and refund it."

I want to use the saleid to link the ipn response transactionid. I worked out that they are the same number.

What I am not sure of, is when they say  "Once a payment is complete" does that mean you have executed it, or that it is marked completed? what happens when you get a echeck, it is marked pending, how do I get the sale id then?

Comment: You said the IPN response transactionid is the same number?  That's how you get it, though you said yourself that, until the payment is complete, it's not really a sale, so that number probably won't be of any use to you until the payment completes.  Pending payments are not complete; completed means executed.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Payment is complete it is considered a sale.

Below is a link to another Stack Post that is similar to this question about pending transactions:

[Stack Post on Pending Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413652/paypal-status-pending-and-delivery/23415129#23415129)

That post includes information on reasons a transaction might be pending. Also has information on Sales vs Authorization API Calls.

Here are the basics for Instant Payment Notification, in case you need it:
[Instant Payment Notification Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Just in case you need it, here is a link to the IPN Simulator:
[PayPal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)

Comment: I understand why it may be pending, my question boils down to this.
"Once a payment is complete, it is referred to as a sale" does this mean no longer pending and is marked complete, or just that you have executed the payment and therefor you have completed the process? 
Thanks

Comment: Once a payment is completed it is a sale