# PayPal payment state is pending?

Tags: php, paypal, state, payment

I'm implementing a paypal payment with PHP.
The code targets the sandbox at the moment.

After I was processing

`$result = $payment->execute($objPaymentExecution, $apiContext)`

the `state` in the result object is `pending`.

Is it because of the sandbox?
Will the state be completed or approved on live (non-sandbox) requests?

What should be processed when the state is pending?

Should the seller hand out his article on pending state?

PS: The sample of the Rest-API-Kit gets the same result!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing all the data you're sending, it's difficult to say for sure.

But in "real life" PayPal, a state of Pending usually means that the buyer is trying to pay using money from the bank account (maybe they have insufficient funds in their PayPal account), which is an eCheque. This may take up to 10 days to clear, at which point your IPN system should receive a new notification saying that the payment is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question that talks about pending payments. Both Answers give the reasons for pending payments:

[Stack Question about Pending Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413652/paypal-status-pending-and-delivery/23415129#23415129)

I've copied and pasted part of the answer from the above question:
There is one other reason why the Payment status is pending. If you are sending doAuthorization then the funds will always be in a status of pending until you capture the funds.

Directly from the PayPal Documentation: For example, an unsettled authorization's PaymentStatus is set to Pending; however, its PendingReason is set to authorization, which is not related to payment review.